# How to select the value of a link button in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-selectors

I have a gridview i am trying to select the value of a link button clicked on a specific row of gridview. below is my code and it is erroring out due to the improper selecting of link button in gridview. Please help me in figuring this out.

**on page load this is the error**

> ASP.Test_aspx does not contain a definition for 'lnkview' and no
>   extension method 'lnkview' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.createsegment_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

**function:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

             if($('#<%=this.lnkview.ClientID %>').length){
              $('#this.lnkview').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#plnClone').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        width: 550,
                        height: 250,
                        open: function(type, data) {
                            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            $('#CancelClone').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#plnClone').dialog('close');
            });
            //
            if ($('#hfdCloneOffer').val() == "DUPLICATE") {
                $('#plnClone').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 550,
                    height: 250,
                    open: function(type, data) {
                        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                    }
                });
                //
                // Scroll to Page Top
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 800);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second line of your code appears to be missing the server tags.

```
$('#this.lnkview')
```

Should become

```
$('#<%=this.lnkview.ClientID %>')
```

**EDIT**
Looking at your markup, I don't think you'll be able to do a lnkView.ClientID on it outside of the grid row. Suggest you use put a class on your linkbutton and use it as a selector instead.

**MORE EDIT**
Something like this should work

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="lnkViewClass">

          $('.lnkViewClass').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#plnClone').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 550,
                    height: 250,
                    open: function(type, data) {
                        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, i used the second syntax as well it still shows the same error. Is it because the linkbutton is in the gridview and i need to add the gridview reference in the code?

Comment: Can you please add that syntax here. I am a newbiew to C#. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have element with id 'lnkview' in your aspx code?  You are calling this here '#<%=this.lnkview.ClientID %>'

Comment: yes,this is the item template i am using in the gridview<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" HeaderStyle-Width="3%">
 <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" CausesValidation="false">
                                                                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: You can not access elements inside gridview. Try using data or css selectors